# Change resolution of SRTM

Tags: resolution, srtm

Currently, I am trying to change the resolution of an SRTM downloaded via SRTM Downloader.

Problem is the following: I need it in 1 Pixel Resolution but can't find a working way, either the heightmap change to 1 Pixel for the Complete Image over resampling methods or other things go wrong.

I tried already four days to fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: I suppose you want the pixel size to be 1 m? Be aware that changing the resolution will change the data, since it needs to be resampled.

Comment: exactly . im reffering to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clbjK4yEGMk later i want import it in ue4 but qgis is its own challenge

Comment: Which CRS is the data in? Probably something degree based, hence you get one large pixel when choosing pixelsize = 1. You need to transform/reproject your data to a fitting local UTM-strip.

Comment: tryed to poste thisd in a better way but it didnt let me  https://pastebin.com/Ft8x1Dm9

Comment: Try again. One probably edited your question body.

Comment: oordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
 LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
 CS[ellipsoidal,2],
 AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
 ORDER[1],
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
 ORDER[2],
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (40.999861111000001,49.000138888999999)
Pixel Size = (0.000277777777839,-0.000277777777839)

Comment: okey its still processing but i think it goes , Many thanks Erik i could kiss you